# php mysql 3 dynamic drop list with ajax jquery

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, drop-down-menu

i am creating  dynamic drop list using php mysql + ajax jquery   that the populate of second drop list  is based on the selection of the first and third is based on the selection of the second but it did not work  can anyone help me ???

## dbconfig.php

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "****";
$password = "***";
$db = "lam_el_chamel_db";
?>
```

## select.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function(){
            $("select#district").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#village").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#governorate").change(function(){

            $("select#district").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#district").html("<option>wait...</option>");

            $("select#village").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#village").html("<option>wait...</option>");

            var id = $("select#governorate option:selected").attr('value');
            $.post("select_district.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                $("select#district").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("select#district").html(data);
            });

            var id2 = $("select#district option:selected").attr('value');
            $.post("select_village.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                $("select#village").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("select#village").html(data);
            });

        $("form#select_form").submit(function(){
            var gover = $("select#governorate option:selected").attr('value');
            var dist = $("select#district option:selected").attr('value');



            if(gover>0 && dist>0)
            {
                var result = $("select#district option:selected").html();
                $("#result").html('your choice: '+result);
            }
            else
            {
                $("#result").html("you must choose two options!");
            }
            if(dist>0 && village>0)
            {
                var result = $("select#village option:selected").html();
                $("#result").html('your choice: '+result);
            }
             else
            {
                $("#result").html("you must choose three options!");
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php include "select.class.php"; ?>
        <form id="select_form">
            Choose a governorate:<br />
            <select id="governorate">

            <?php echo $opt->ShowGovernorate(); ?>


            </select>
            <br /><br />

           choose a district:<br />
            <select id="district">
                <option value="0">choose...</option>
            </select>
            <br /><br />

            choose a village:<br />
            <select id="village">
                <option value="0">choose...</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="confirm" />
        </form>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

## select_class.php

```
<?php 
 class SelectList
{
    protected $conn;

        public function __construct()

        {
           $this->DbConnect();
        }
    protected function DbConnect()
   {
    include "dbconfig.php";
    $this->conn = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) OR die("Unable to connect to the database");
    mysql_select_db($db,$this->conn) OR die("can not select the database $db");
    return TRUE;
   }  

    public function ShowGovernorate()
    {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM governorate";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
            $governorate = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
            {
                $governorate .= '<option value="' . $row['governorate_id'] . '">' . $row['governorate_name'] . '</option>';
            }
            return $governorate;

    }
    public function ShowDistrict()
   {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM districts WHERE governorate_id=$_POST[id]";
    $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
    var_dump($res);
    $district = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
      {
        $district .= '<option value="' . $row['district_id'] . '">' . $row['district_name'] . '</option>';
      }
    return $district;
   }

   public function ShowVillage()
   {
    $sql = "SELECT village_id, village_name FROM village WHERE district_id=$_POST[id2]";
    $res = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
    $village = '<option value="0">choose...</option>';
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
       {
         $village .='<option value="' .$row['village_id'] . '">' . $row['village_name'] . '</option>';
       }
       return $village;
   }


}   
$opt = new SelectList(); 


?>
```

## select_district.php

```
<?php
include "select.class.php";
echo $opt->ShowDistrict();
?>
```

## select_village.php

```
<?php
include "select.class.php";
echo $opt->ShowVillage();
?>
```

i think it has something within the select.php but i did not know what is the error

Comment: Your code is prone to SQL injection. Use parameterized queries instead. And "it did not work" is not very descriptive. Can you tell what happens instead of the expected result?

Comment: @ Marcel Korpel  did not work mean that the second and the third drop list display just the default option **choose**

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call is done on the document.ready function. You should bind the ajax to the dropdown change function like:

```
$("select#district option:selected").change(function(){
id = $(this).val(); 
$.post("select_village.php", {id:id}, function(data){
    $("select#village").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("select#village").html(data);
});
```

Hope that helps